# Issue related to rabbitmq-plugins "Can't open /usr/local/bin/rabbitmq-env"

Tags: ubuntu, rabbitmq

When I run `sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management`, I am getting this issue.

My ubuntu version 20.04.03LTS.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5poF9.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code). For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.